# Excel Combining Two tables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having problem with pairing two tables togheter, the second table corespondst to the first, so i need some sort of formula that converts the second table into the first as shown in the sample. If in the 0.5mm colum the D is 1 than in the first table under the P colum i need to put 1, but if the number is 2 in the second table then i need tu put 1 in the P and Z colum, thats goes for the 2mm colum alsou but then instead of 1 then i need to put 2, 
(IF D=1 than P=1 IF D=2 than P=1 and Z=1)

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/580611/zskAoYUo3kNRrFyA/testbook.xlsx

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Superuser! Instead of posting a link to the spreadsheet, could you please post a screenshot or two instead?

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/gmm6bjnbl/
https://postimg.org/image/3tkjfzlj5/
Here are the screenshoots

Comment: also i forgot to mention that in table2 in a single raw the sum can bi only 4 or less, ant that coresponds to the table1 if the sum is 4 than all 4 fields in table1 have a number